# Why not add boolean constants to first order logic in model theory?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, quantifier-elimination

I'm working through Marker's (Model Theory: An Introduction) presentation of quantifier elimination. Things get a bit awkward with the use of formulas like $x_1 = x_1$ to represent truth, and $x_1 \neq x_1$ to represent falsehood. Is there any reason not to just introduce propositional constants representing truth and falsehood as part of the boolean logic of a language in model theory?

That is, to allow $T$ and $F$ as first order logical formulas where $T$ is interpreted as always true and $F$ is interpreted as always false.

Does anything break? Does this make any proofs more complicated? It seems like adding these  makes the presentation of quantifier elimination easier: if one starts with a formula with no free variables and one quantifier and then eliminates that quantifier one should be left with either $T$ or $F$, and a good quantifier elimination algorithm should naturally handle this sort of special case.

Comment: I'm not a specialist, but I find that representing truth by $x_1=x_1$ (for example), makes it more evident for when we want to explicitly prove the equivalence between the original and the quantifier-free formula, especially the right-to-left implication. I don't think there would be an issue with what you are saying though, but again, I am no expert.

Comment: It's just one of the minimization hobbies of logicians

Answer (score 3):

You're exactly right: nothing breaks if we include "true" and "false" as formulas (usually denoted $\top$ and $\bot$), and I think a number of things are simpler with this convention. My notes on model theory [here](https://akruckman.faculty.wesleyan.edu/files/2019/07/Lecture-Notes.pdf) develop all the basics, including quantifier elimination, in a setting where first-order logic includes $\top$ and $\bot$.

Comment: I would stress you MUST include some logic constant if you want QE in, e.g., $\mathbb Q,<$. Otherwise there would be no qf equivalent of $\forall x\ x=x$

Comment: @PrimoPetri I agree with you! But if you look carefully at a lot of sources (e.g. Marker or Chang & Keisler), they allow things like saying $\forall x\, x = x$ is equivalent to the quantifier-free formula $y = y$. I think the correct definition of quantifier elimination should say that every formula is equivalent to a quantifier-free formula *in the same variable context* (with the same variables appearing free), and for this, yes, you need to include a logical constant for theories like DLO that don't have constant symbols.